# Why did Ego kill Peter's mother?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

First, Ego loved her.

Second, if Ego needed to visit his brain to keep his human form in existence and if he didn't want her to feel bad alone, he could have simply brought her with him to Ego, the planet. BTW, she really felt bad when she was at her death bed and he wasn't there beside her (so this hypothesis is out of question).

Why exactly Ego kill her? Also, why didn't he give her instant painless death instead of making her suffer for several months?

Comment: This was explained right in the film

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Because his life, his love, his lady, is the sea

Ego explained it to Peter,

> I returned to Earth to see her three times. And I knew if I returned a fourth I'd never leave. The Expansion, the reason for my very existence, would be over. So, I did what I had to do. But it broke my heart to put that tumor in her head.

In other words, his love for her jeopardized his purpose, which remained the most important thing to him. That could also have been the case had he taken her with him too.

Comment: Then, why didn't he gave her instant painless death?

Comment: We don't know. It's never addressed.

Comment: @Discovery Would you want to watch someone you love die? By using a tumour he knew he wouldn't be seeing her become ill, he knew he did it but he never saw it's effects.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That's a nice reasoning..

Comment: [Similar answer of mine](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/73075/11244) You're welcome to use any points from there if you'd like, since they're similar.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think he loved her more than himself? Why do you think Ego told the truth to Peter about anything?

It makes sense to kill her slowly. Ego needs Peter to grow up, to know the story behind his father and to want to find him.

Why kill her at all then? So Peter doesn't have anyone who loves him tying him to the planet and so he will leave with the first person who says:

"Hey kid. Wanna meet your real father? He sends me, here's his picture/video, come on, it's not like there is anything keeping you here. Wanna go to space and meet aliens and your dad? Space is cool, right, aliens are cool and meeting your dad is the coolest?"

Which leads to fridge logic: maybe other kids were Celestials too, but Ego just killed them before they grew up and their powers got the chance to manifest.